# How to Send Back to Client After 'app.post' in Express.JS

Tags: javascript, express

I am currently developing a deployment pipeline that can serve a text-summarization deep learning model running in chrome extension, which summarize a highlighted text block in the browser.

my simple front looks as following written in pure javascript

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {

    document.write(selection[0]);

    var post =
        '<form action="http://localhost:8080/client_txt" method="POST" id="hlgt_form">' +
        '<input type="hidden" id="hlgt" name="hlgt" value="">' +
        '</form>';

    document.write(post);

    document.getElementById('hlgt').value = selection[0];
    // it stores highlights into value of <input>

    document.getElementById('hlgt_form').submit();
});
```

and my Express.JS server looks as following

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const python = require('python-shell');

// define conda specific python
const python_path = '/Users/****/anaconda3/envs/****/bin/python';

// define sysArgs for python script
const mode = "decode";
const data_path = "/Users/****/Downloads/finished_files/chunked/test_000.bin";
const vocab_path = "/Users/****/Downloads/finished_files/vocab";
const log_root = "/Users/****/Downloads";
const exp_name = "pretrained_model_tf1.2.1";


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/client_txt', (req, ) => {

    const text = `${req.body.hlgt}`;

    console.log(text);

    /* python runs in express js */
    const options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonPath: python_path,
        pythonOptions: ['-u'],
        scriptPath: '/Users/****/project/text-summarizer/',

        args: [ '--hlgt', text,
                '--mode', mode,
                '--data_path', data_path,
                '--vocab_path', vocab_path,
                '--log_root', log_root,
                '--exp_name', exp_name,
                '--max_enc_steps', 400,
                '--max_dec_steps', 120,
                '--coverage', 1,
                '--single_pass', 1,
                '--batch_size', 1,
                '--beam_size', 1]

    };
    //TODO: Get return val from python script not print val
    python.PythonShell.run('run_summarization.py',
        options,
        function (err, results) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("\n ## summary ##\n" +
            results[results.length-1] + "\n"); // python "print" val stored in results
    });


    /******************************/

});

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

The server side gets the posted text from the front that is highlighted, and pass it to deep learning python code with the text as `sysarg`.

The `result` has a python terminal printed outputs and the last one is the text string that is summarized.

I'd like to send the result back to client.

What should I add? Is it possible while I keep using `post` method?

Comment: Express will wait, you can do `res.json(results)` inside your python callback function. But if its going to hang for abit, it would be better to use websocket, as can send you the result, rather then you waiting.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the response part.

```
app.post('/client_txt', (req, ) => {
```

Change to

```
app.post('/client_txt', (req, res) => {
  // After all your processing and getting of the result.
  res.send(results);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how could I receive result in front-side that is sent by `res.send(results)`?

Comment: @delinco If you put `document.getElementById('hlgt_form').submit();` inside a async function and called `var value = await document.getElementById('hlgt_form').submit();` does that work?  Personally I would look into using some type of httpService like these https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/

Comment: I had put `async` in front of `function` and put `await` also as you guided. However, I'd like to check whether the value really contains the sent text value from server, so I had added `var value_str = String(value)` and `document.write(value_str)` but it doesn't write down anything on my `iframe`. Any hint guidance could your provide?